# How to split strings by percent

Tags: vba

I have a function that should split a string by %. Sample string: "20% after deductible 40% after deductible 30% after deductible"

It should be split into: "20% after deductible", "40% after deductible", "30% after deductible"

```
Public Sub SplitPercentOnly(ByVal strText As String, ByVal lngCount3 As Long)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strTemps As String
    Dim lngPos As Long
    Dim lngChar As Long
    Dim intCell As Integer
    Dim strSplit() As String
    strTemps = ""
    intCell = 2
    lngPos = 1
    lngChar = 0

    strSplit = Split(strText, " ")

    For i = LBound(strSplit) To UBound(strSplit)

            If i = LBound(strSplit) Then
               strTemps = strTemps & " " & strSplit(i)
            ElseIf IsNumeric(Left(strSplit(i), 1)) = True And i <> LBound(strSplit) Then
                'wksMain.Cells(lngCount3, intCell).Value = Trim(strTemps)
                strTemps = ""
                strTemps = strSplit(i)
                intCell = intCell + 1
            ElseIf i = UBound(strSplit) Then
                strTemps = strTemps & " " & strSplit(i)
                wksMain.Cells(lngCount3, intCell).Value = Trim(strTemps)
            Else

                strTemps = strTemps & " " & strSplit(i)
            End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

It successfully splits it BUT has an extra empty string. It splits it into 4 strings with the inclusion of a n empty string instead of 3 strings: "20% after deductible", "40% after deductible", "30% after deductible"

Comment: I'm a bit confused.. in your code you write `strSplit = Split(strText, " ")` which splits on `" "` not `"%"` ? Also I don't think you want to split on `%` but rather on the actual number that is deductible i.e. 20,40,60. You could either define and check for substrings or if there is never a 100% deduction you could go by character position. So split on the 2nd value left of  the %.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a function which returns a Variant array you can then do whatever you want with.

```
Public Function SplitPercentOnly(ByVal strText As String) As Variant

    Dim re As RegExp
    Set re = New RegExp
    With re
        .Pattern = " (\d+%)"
        .Global = True
    End With

    SplitPercentOnly = Split(re.Replace(strText, vbTab & "$1"), vbTab)
End Function
```

(NOTE: It requires a reference to the VBScript Regular Expressions library.)

So your sample input `"20% after deductible 40% after deductible 30% after deductible"` returns the array `("20% after deductible","40% after deductible","30% after deductible")`.